# Cambiar for each por un for normal

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Tengo un Objeto que es films y con este voy a llamar una función ajax para que me muestre un titulo de una pelicula (En la api me mandan 4 o más) para recorrer cada pelicula hice un FOREACH pero quiero que solo me muestre uno así que intento con for (var j=0; j<1; j++) y me dice que syntax error con var.

No sé como hacer para que solo muestre una película, necesito cambiar ese foreach

Este es mi codigo

```
function peliculas(e)
{

 event = e;
clicked=e.target;
//console.log(clicked);
clicked.getAttribute('films');
films=JSON.parse(clicked.getAttribute('films'));



 var resultados = document.querySelector(".results ul");

// AQUI ESTA EL FOREACH QUE ME MUESTRA TODAS LAS PELICULAS
 films.forEach(function(url)
  {
    //console.log(43, url);
    var httpRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange= function()
    {
      if (httpRequest.readyState ===4)
    {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200){

        film= JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        console.log(film.title);

          list=document.createElement("li");
          list.innerHTML=film.title;
          list.innerHTML=film.opening_crawl;
          resultados.appendChild(list);

      }

    }
  }


  httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
  })

   }
```

Mi problema es con el objeto 
es esta linea

films.forEach(function(url)) necesito ese objeto films por que si no me sale undefined

pero al hacer films[0].function(url) no me reconoce el parámetro

Comment: Hola Daniela. Puedes explicar más, por ejemplo, mostrar el intento de `for` que has hecho y qué error o problema te genera?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Si solo necesitas uno, no necesitas un bucle: usa films[0] para obtener la URL de la primera película y listo

Comment: Como ha dicho @PabloLozano, no necesitas un bucle para obtener sólo el  primer film, puedes acceder a él por su índice. De todos modos, me parece que el principal problema es un error de diseño de la API o de uso: es extraño que te mande más datos de los que necesitas consumir. ¿Acaso alguna tienda, si compras 1 pantalón te manda 4? ¿No quebraría tal tienda? Con eso quiero decir que la API que estás consultando posiblemente tenga formas de acceso para que envíe un solo film. Y si la API depende de ti, considera que debe ser capaz de enviar exactamente lo que se le pide, no datos de más.

Comment: @A.Cedano Como curiosidad te comento que he visto ya media docena de preguntas que hacen referencia a este [API REST](https://swapi.co/api/people/1) , creo que el OP tiene ya varias hechas...

Comment: @PabloLozano ahí está precisamente la prueba de lo que digo en mi comentario. En el enlace que indicas aparecen en efecto 4 films... si se quisiera obtener información sobre el primero de esos films, la forma correcta de consultar la API sería: `https://swapi.co/api/films/2/`, de ese modo, se obtendría toda la información del film en específico. Generalmente en un API se pide la información que se necesita, ni más ni  menos. Y si por alguna casualidad se necesita la información de la persona y el primer film relacionado con ella, también la API debería tener esa posibilidad de consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en lugar de

```
films.forEach(function (url) {
   //codigo a ejecutar que usa el parámetro url...
}
```

usa

```
//codigo a ejecutar que usa el parametro url, pero sustituyendo
// url por films[0]
```

Por ejemplo:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
request.open('GET',films[0]);
```